# CSS Issues with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am scratching my head trying to figure what could be causing this issue I am having with my menu on Internet Explorer.  It looks fine on all browsers except IE.In IE the menu is almost double the size it should be.

I imagine it has something to do with line height, because I can not see any sort of padding or margin in my css that might be causing this. Take a look at the image below and the link is below as well.

Image of IE Screen Shot:
[image]

Link: [New Growth Partners](http://www.new.growthpartners.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this on IE, and the issue is on line 20 of style.css

This line is not valid in IE "line-height: initial;"

In the universal fix for this would be to set it. I think "line-height: 18px;" looks good.

[Joseph Sanatar IE Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXchA.png)

[Joseph Sanatar IE Fix with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePuAs.png)

Comment: The issue also occurs in IE 8 and 9.  I don't have a PC to test on, I am using Browser Stack.

Comment: I still have not made it home, but I have a windows 7 computer I can test this on tonight. Browser Stack does no justice to how the devices / browsers actually render. So I will get you some screen shots.

Comment: Great! Thank you Joseph.

Comment: So Joseph I did some trouble shooting and it is 100% line height issues, which to me is very weird.  I suppose I would have to change those rules by loading a different CSS for that specific issue.

Comment: I would imagine all line height rules would remain the same.

Comment: If you do change it, just use the IE specific CSS hack. Just add the same line with the new height, and add \9 before the semicolon.

Comment: Erik, I updated my answer. Did that work?

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have tried to find the hack you are referring to, how would that look in the actual stylesheet.

Comment: Joseph I found it, it worked, thanks for your help!